# Windows Server 2008/2012 DFS won't replicate one folder

Tags: windows, directory, dfs

I have a problem with Windows 2008 DC replicating to Windows 2012 DC. I've been dealing with this for 6 months.

The replicated folder contains 15 folders and 0 files in the root.
All of the folders except for 1 replicate just fine. Unfortunately, the files in those folders are not ever changed. All of the updates and new data are stored in the 1 folder that won't replicate.

My (weekly) work around has been to delete that folder (22gb) and manually copy the updated folder over to the dfs server.

I have checked for filters and there none setup. There are only 2 servers in this replication group AND they are on the same IP LAN ID and subnet.

One more piece of information, though the DFS topology test reports that replication will be successful, the report itself doesn't contain any text..

Several times, I have tried deleting the replication group and recreating it. But still no luck.

Please help me....

Comment: What is the version of dfsrs.exe?

Comment: The file version is 6.1.7601.17514

Comment: What does `dfsrdiag ReplicationState` show?

Comment: BlueCompute the output is: Summary

  Active inbound connections: 0
  Updates received: 0

  Active outbound connections: 0
  Updates sent out: 0

Operation Succeeded

Comment: @MillerTech: I would update the DFSR components to the latest versions.  See: List of currently available hotfixes for Distributed File System (DFS) technologies in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2008 R2: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968429 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002288

Comment: Thank you for the links Greg Askew... I will try applying update 2680906  and 3002288 since they appear to address my exact problem... I will report back once I have applied the updates.